# How to access the values of arraylist using variable in vm file?

Tags: java, arraylist, velocity

I m using this code to access the values in arraylist:

```
#foreach($bean in $requestList)
  #set($i = $velocityCount)
 #set($rowFormatComponents = $UIRowFormatList[$i] )
```

Im getting parser exception saying

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "[" Was expecting one of:
<RPAREN> ...
    <WHITESPACE> ...
    "-" ...
    "+" ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...
    "%" ...
    <LOGICAL_AND> ...
    <LOGICAL_OR> ...
    <LOGICAL_LT> ...
    <LOGICAL_LE> ...
    <LOGICAL_GT> ...
    <LOGICAL_GE> ...
    <LOGICAL_EQUALS> ...
    <LOGICAL_NOT_EQUALS> ...
    <DOT> ...
```

Help in finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The indexed access for lists is new in Velocity 1.7. Based on the stacktrace, I think you're using an older version. Depending on how much older it is, you can either:

1. Access it using the `List` methods, for example `#set($rowFormatComponents = $UIRowFormatList.get($i) )`
2. Use [the list tool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/1.4/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ListTool.html), if you have it enabled or if you can enable it
3. If you have control over what gets in the context, you could use a real `List` instead of an array, in which case you can use list methods

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,but thats also not working for me.Amd i m using 1.6 version of velocity